# Unable to access Drop Down List object in ASPX page in order to populate it from my code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

Error Message: the name 'DriverObjNameDD' does not exist in current context (Lines in cdoe behind where 'DriverObjNameDD' is referenced)

It appears that the code behind methods are in the same namespace as the .aspx file where the InsertItemTemplate would be. I believe the placeholder would also be a part of linking the InsertItemTemplate so that there would be access, but that does not seem to be the case.

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EstimationToolForms.EstimationAdmin
{
    public partial class CreateTypeTemplateObject : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultEstimateConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM et_TypeObject"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                DataTable TypeObjdt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter TypeObjda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                TypeObjda.Fill(TypeObjdt);
                TypeTemplateLV.DataSource = TypeObjdt;
                TypeTemplateLV.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DriverObjName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ListViewItem item = TypeTemplateLV.Items[];
        //DropDownList DriverDescriptionDD = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("DriverObjName");

        //DropDownList DriverDescriptionDD = (DropDownList)TypeTemplateLV.FindControl("DriverObjName"); //
        //int Driverid = Int32.Parse(DriverDescriptionDD.DataValueField);  //

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultEstimateConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM et_DriverObject"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                DataTable DrvrObjdt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter DrvrObjda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DrvrObjda.Fill(DrvrObjdt);


                DriverObjNameDD.DataSource = DrvrObjdt;
                DriverObjNameDD.DataBind();
                DriverObjNameDD.DataTextField = "Name";
                DriverObjNameDD.DataValueField = "ID";
                DriverObjNameDD.DataBind();


                
                DropDownList DriverDropDown = (DropDownList) TypeTemplateLV.FindControl("DriverObjName");
                DriverObjName.DataSource = DrvrObjdt;
                TypeTemplateLV.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

**Aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="CreateTypeTemplateObject.aspx.cs" Inherits="EstimationToolForms.EstimationAdmin.CreateTypeTemplateObject" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="TypeTemplateLV" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" GroupPlaceholderID="groupplaceholder">

    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:TreeView ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Namelbl" runat="server" Text="Task Name: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TypeNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeName") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DriverDropDownlbl" runat="server" Text="Driver Name: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DriverObjNameDD" DataTextField= ></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Indicatorlbl" runat="server" Text="Check if LOE: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="LOEIndicatorCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("LOEIndicator") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Orderlbl" runat="server" Text="Order of math operation: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="OrderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Order") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="BaseVallbl" runat="server" Text="Base Value: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="BaseValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BaseValue") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="MathOperator" runat="server" Text="Math Operation: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="MathOperatorDropDown" runat="server"  >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="*">*</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="+">+</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OptDescription1lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt1Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt1ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt1Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="OptDescription2lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt2Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt2ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt2Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="OptDescription3lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt3Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt3ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt3Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="OptDescription4lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt4Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt4ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt4Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="OptDescription5lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt5Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt5ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt5Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="OptDescription6lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt6Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Opt6ValueTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Opt6Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TypeNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TypeName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TypeDriverObjIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TypeDriverObjID") %>' />
            </td>
            <!--td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="LOEIndicatorCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
            </td-->
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OrderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Order") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="BaseValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BaseValue") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="MathOperatorLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MathOperator") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt1ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt1Value") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt2ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt2Value") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt3ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt3Value") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt4ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt4Value") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt5ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt5Value") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Opt6ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Opt6Value") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                            <th runat="server">ID</th>
                            <th runat="server">TypeName</th>
                            <th runat="server">TypeDriverObjID</th>
                            <th runat="server">LOEIndicator</th>
                            <th runat="server">Order</th>
                            <th runat="server">BaseValue</th>
                            <th runat="server">MathOperator</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt1Value</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt2Value</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt3Value</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt4Value</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt5Value</th>
                            <th runat="server">Opt6Value</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="groupplaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>


</asp:ListView>
```

</asp:Content>

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to run a query for each entry in the list view.

If so, you will have to iterate through the list and use something along the lines of `(DropDownList)(TypeTemplateLV.Items[{index}].FindControl("DriverObjNameDD"))` and manipulate that object in the loop.  You cannot access that field without accessing the indexed value of the `ListView`.

I also noticed you included `DriverObjNameDD.DataBind();` twice.  You should probably remove one of those.